# Which Magento product type should I use?

Tags: magento, product

Magento ultra-noob here. I am setting up a Magento store which will offer bottled salsas. One of the product offering requirements is a mix and match case (total 24 pieces) of 2 different types of salsas. So, for example, you could order 1 case with 4 of Salsa A and 20 of Salsa B.

Which *product type* should I choose (from:Simple,Grouped,Configurable,Bundle) to accomplish this and what else do I maybe need to know that would help me accomplish this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: According to me... First you have to create two Simple product 1:- Salsa A and 2:- Salsa B and then you have to create a one Configurable product which have that two associated products(Salsa A With the Qty of 4 and Salasa B With the Qty of 20).

Comment: Thanks Vishal. I guess that I need to add more to my description or requirements. Basically, a customer would select a "Full Case" option, and then get to define how many of each salsa they would prefer to form a case of 24 total. Is the "Configurable" product type still the correct one for this application/requirement?

Comment: Yes, You must use configurable product. In the configurable product user can choose the qty of the associated products.